# JSF errors and redirect

Tags: jsf-2

I've a page that shows an item via its id: `item.xhtml?id=xxx`

If no id is provided the list of all items is shown.

In the same page there is a form used to update item's fields.
Using `<f:viewParam>` and an hidden input I'm able to show `item.xhtml?id=xxx` again when I submit the form. But if a validation error occurs (I use Bean Validation) the item.xhtml appears with the list of all items and the error message. Is there a way to redirect even if an error occurs?

**PS:** why jsf takes away the querystring from urls? I mean that these kind of problems would no exists if the rendered form action was `/context/page.xhtml?query=string` instead of just `/context/page.xhtml`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Duplicate question: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/6885887/620338](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6885887/620338)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the managed bean in the view scope by `@ViewScoped`. If you really need your bean to be request scoped for some reason, then you need to pass the parameter along by `<f:param>`.

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
    <f:param name="paramName" value="#{param.paramName}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

As to the form action URL, this is by design. You can override this by providing your own `ViewHandler` implementation wherein you override the `getActionURL()` method accordingly.

Comment: @Alf: please describe "does not work" in more detail. It's not supported in JSF 1.x, but it's definitely supported in JSF 2.x.

Comment: it doesn't work because if a validation error occurs the page shown is item.xhtml not item.xhtml?id=xxx. I tried with `@ViewScoped`. This works but I'm using CDI.

Comment: The parameter is been sent as POST request and not GET. The validation error is apparently caused because you used the wrong `<f:param>` name or value. As to keeping the URL same, use a custom `ViewHandler` wherein you override `getActionURL()` accordingly, as said.